# Uploaded a bunch of contacts and many were assigned foreign countries

Tags: import, data-import

I uploaded a bunch of contacts with addresses but without country specified. We have mostly United States contacts. Oddly CiviCRM assigned many of them Hungary as their country. Other countries also were assigned - El Salvador, Suriname, Slovakia, Soloman Islands, Nicaragua, and Uruguay also got assigned to some contacts, but for the most part it was Hungary.

We did not have a default country setup in localization.

Any idea why? Civi 5.48 / Wordpress

Answer (score 2):

If you upload contacts without a country, CiviCRM will try its best to find a matching state and will assign it whatever country that state has. If you use abbreviations, it will assign it the first country that has a state with that abbreviation.

Always be sure to include country when importing contacts with addresses.